# Using pivot wider in R

Tags: r

I am having trouble converting a particular dataset from long to wide.

```
col1           col2
ID             55.
animal.        bear
shape.         circle
ID             67.
animal.        cat
shape.         square
```

```
I want it to look like

ID.   animal.  shape
55.    bear.   circle
67.    cat.    square
```

I'm sorry if this has already been answered I just can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to create a sequence by 'col1' before doing the `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
df1 %>% 
   mutate(rn = rowid(col1)) %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = col1, values_from = col2) %>% 
   select(-rn) %>% 
   type.convert(as.is = TRUE)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 3
     ID animal. shape.
  <dbl> <chr>   <chr> 
1    55 bear    circle
2    67 cat     square
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(col1 = c("ID", "animal.", "shape.", "ID", "animal.", 
"shape."), col2 = c("55.", "bear", "circle", "67.", "cat", "square"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I realized after I posted the question that some IDs have multiple observations in the other columns. How can I make it so there is another column called "animal2" that just returns NA if there is only one observation? I can post a new question with an example if needed!

Comment: @alex can you post as a new question. thanks

Comment: yes i just did, thanks!

Comment: @alex I posted a solution there.  Pleaes check

Comment: I don't see it, it says it was deleted

Comment: @alex sorry was busy, so if i left it there, somebody will downvote

Answer (score 1):

Yet another solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                    col1 = c("ID","animal.",
                             "shape.","ID","animal.","shape."),
              col2 = c("55.", "bear", "circle", "67.", "cat", "square")
      )

df %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = col1, values_from = col2, values_fn = list) %>% 
  unnest(cols = c(ID, animal., shape.))

#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>   ID    animal. shape.
#>   <chr> <chr>   <chr> 
#> 1 55.   bear    circle
#> 2 67.   cat     square
```